# Button click if specific url

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make sure that when going to a certain url, the button that is on the page is pressed, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
<script>
    let loginInp = document.querySelector('.login-form--hide');
    let emailInp = document.querySelector('.email-form--hide');
    let sendInp = document.querySelector('.send-form--hide');


    let loginLoc = window.localStorage.getItem('name');
    let emailLoc = window.localStorage.getItem('email');

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

        if (window.location.href === 'https://url/success/') {
            loginInp.value = loginLoc;
            emailInp.value = emailLoc;

            console.log('Worked');

            //sendInp.click();


        }
     });




</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What is output of `console.log(document.location.href)`

Comment: Maybe not the reason of the failing but since your are using the DOMContentLoaded event maybe your should query your DOM elements (the inputs) only in that callbak and not before. Regarding where you put your script in the page these could be null.